# Why is my baked object different from the original?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I need to bake an image from blender in order to export it to Unity. I have done this several times, but this time I am finding a bit of a problem. Once i bake the image it gets darker and does not look anything like the image i had obtained earlier. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I will attach some images to show you what I mean. Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help me[image: this is how the object looks before baking] [image: another image of the object before baking] [image: this is how it looks after baking] [image: other images of the object after baking] [image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? maybe it's a refresh problem and replug the Normal Map?

Comment: Sure, what do i have to do to share the file? I can only see how to share images or links

Comment: Save the file with the high-poly + low-poly, then upload and copy paste the URL it will create: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Thank you! this should be the link: https://pasteall.org/blend/4140c47e3658474fbf952311eddbddf1, let me know if it works

Comment: I can only see the low-poly version (I guess it's the low-poly), plus you didn't pack the normal map image, so maybe at least pack it (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share again?

Comment: never mind, i am new to blender and don't know how to do what you ask. Thank you anyway, i will try something else, if i can later i will share the file as you ask!

Comment: I think i solved the problem, i made some mistakes in the uv unwrapping, thank you again!

Comment: Oh ok, great then   ;)